# Python requests send certificate as string

Tags: python, heroku, python-requests

I cant seem to get the handshake working properly.

```
cert = 'path/to/cert_file.pem'
url = 'https://example.com/api'

requests.get(url, cert=cert, verify=True)
```

This is fine when I use it locally where I have the file physically. 
We host our application on heroku and use environvariables.

The requests module doesnt seem to accept certificates as strings. eg.

```
$ export CERTIFICATE="long-list-of-characters"

requests.get(url, cert=get_env('CERTIFICATE'), verify=True)
```

I have also tried something like this:

```
cert = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
cert.write(CERTIFICATE)
cert.seek(0)
requests.get(url, cert=cert.name, verify=True)
```

First of all, it works locally but not on heroku. Anyways, it doesnt feel like a solid solution.
I get a SSL handshake error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Gelbander, who signed the cert_file.pem? Is it self-signed by your custom/inhouse root Certificate Authority? Have you tried uploading your pem file to Heroku, just to be sure to be sure it works passing the pem full path in Heroku?

Comment: Also I'm not sure using env variables is the preferred way. It's probably better using "heroku certs:add server.crt server.key"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old question, but since I ended up here and the question wasn't answered I figure I'll point to the solution I came up with for a similar question that can be used to solve the OP's problem.

This can be done by monkey patching `requests` using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353645/3243889).

Answer (score 6):

Vasili's answer is technically correct, though per se it doesn't answer your question. The keyfile, truly, must be unencrypted to begin with.

I myself have just resolved a situation like yours. You were on the right path; all you had to do was

**1.** Pass `delete=False` to `NamedTemporaryFile()`, so the file wouldn't be deleted after calling `close()`

**2.** `close()` the tempfile before using it, so it would be saved

Note that this is a very unsafe thing to do. `delete=False`, as I understand, causes the file to stay on disk even after deleting the reference to it. So, to delete the file, you should manually call `os.unlink(tmpfile.name)`.

Doing this with certificates is a huge security risk: you **must** ensure that the string with the certificate is secured and hidden and nobody has access to the server.

Nevertheless, it is quite a useful practice in case of, for example, managing your app both on a Heroku server as a test environment and in a Docker image built in the cloud, where `COPY` directives are not an option. It is also definitely better than storing the file in your git repository :D

Answer (score -4):

As per the `requests` documentation:

> The private key to your local certificate *must* be unencrypted. Currently, Requests does not support using encrypted keys.
>
> You can [also] specify a local cert to use as client side certificate, as a single file (containing the private key and the certificate) or as a tuple of both file's path:

```
requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key'))
```

You must include the path for both public and private key... or you can include the path to a single file that contains both.