# Python requests CA certificates as a string

Tags: python, python-requests, ca

Currently we're using an approach of putting CA Certificates on the server to access third party APIs.

```
certificate_path = os.path.join(CERT_PATH, 'cacert.pem')
certificate_key_path = os.path.join(CERT_PATH, 'cacert.key')
response = requests.get(url, cert=(certificate_path, certificate_key_path))
```

This works,But we're looking for instead of storing CA certificates on the server, store in the `Accounts` Table in the database for security purposes (security cause raised by Customer).

So the questions are:

- Is there any approach we can directly pass CA cert's string to the `requests` directly (other than writing content in to a temp file)?
- Is any other `http` python module support passing CA cert's string in the `http` get/post request?
- Is there any other approach we should use instead of storing them in the database and on the server?

Comment: Read about _Lower-Lower-Level Classes_ of `requests` or use `io.BufferIO(...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one wants to do this without using temporary file, it is possible by overriding the requests SSLContext. Sample can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696785/2167106).

Comment: Exactly, this is what I was looking when the question was asked.

Comment: This approach works, however, it has the downside of adding your client-side cert to *every* request made by the requests library in your process. If you want to supply a client-side cert in memory per request or per session see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353645/3243889)

Answer (score 9):

The example you have provided is passing a client-side cert as shown in the requests [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates).

As it stands there is no way to pass the client cert and key in memory (or as a string).

*Monkey patching to the rescue* - by monkey patching `requests` you can add the ability to load client certs and keys from memory. The following patch enables passing in a client cert and key in a variety formats without breaking the existing functionality.

```
import requests
from OpenSSL.crypto import PKCS12, X509, PKey


def _is_key_file_encrypted(keyfile):
    '''In memory key is not encrypted'''
    if isinstance(keyfile, PKey):
        return False
    return _is_key_file_encrypted.original(keyfile)


class PyOpenSSLContext(requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl.PyOpenSSLContext):
    '''Support loading certs from memory'''
    def load_cert_chain(self, certfile, keyfile=None, password=None):
        if isinstance(certfile, X509) and isinstance(keyfile, PKey):
            self._ctx.use_certificate(certfile)
            self._ctx.use_privatekey(keyfile)
        else:
            super().load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile=keyfile, password=password)


class HTTPAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    '''Handle a variety of cert types'''
    def cert_verify(self, conn, url, verify, cert):
        if cert:
            # PKCS12
            if isinstance(cert, PKCS12):
                conn.cert_file = cert.get_certificate()
                conn.key_file = cert.get_privatekey()
                cert = None
            elif isinstance(cert, tuple) and len(cert) == 2:
                # X509 and PKey
                if isinstance(cert[0], X509) and hasattr(cert[1], PKey):
                    conn.cert_file = cert[0]
                    conn.key_file = cert[1]
                    cert = None
                # cryptography objects
                elif hasattr(cert[0], 'public_bytes') and hasattr(cert[1], 'private_bytes'):
                    conn.cert_file = X509.from_cryptography(cert[0])
                    conn.key_file = PKey.from_cryptography_key(cert[1])
                    cert = None
        super().cert_verify(conn, url, verify, cert)


def patch_requests(adapter=True):
    '''You can perform a full patch and use requests as usual:

    >>> patch_requests()
    >>> requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get')

    or use the adapter explicitly:

    >>> patch_requests(adapter=False)
    >>> session = requests.Session()
    >>> session.mount('https', HTTPAdapter())
    >>> session.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
    '''
    if hasattr(requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_, '_is_key_file_encrypted'):
        _is_key_file_encrypted.original = requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_._is_key_file_encrypted
        requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_._is_key_file_encrypted = _is_key_file_encrypted
    requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.SSLContext = PyOpenSSLContext
    if adapter:
        requests.sessions.HTTPAdapter = HTTPAdapter
```

To use the patch you can do something like the following (assume the above code is in a file called `patch.py`)

```
import os
import requests
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from patch import patch_requests


CLIENT_CERT = serialization.load_pem_x509_certificate(
    os.getenv('CLIENT_CERT'), default_backend())
CLIENT_KEY = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    os.getenv('CLIENT_KEY'), None, default_backend())


# monkey patch load_cert_chain to allow loading
# cryptography certs and keys from memory
patch_requests()


response = requests.get(url, cert=(CLIENT_CERT, CLIENT_KEY))
```

You now have the ability to supply a client cert to requests in memory in as `pyopenssl` object(s) or `cryptography` objects.

Comment: Added `_is_key_file_encrypted()` to patch to support `requests` using `urllib3 >= 1.25`

Comment: Able to load load_pem_x509_certificate from x509 as it was not available under serialization. Getting "400 The SSL certificate error" error. Not sure why this is coming. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to do it via temp files, like this:

```
cert = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
cert.write(CERTIFICATE_AS_STRING)
cert.close()
requests.get(url, cert=cert.name, verify=True)
os.unlink(cert.name)
```

If you'd like to know why this is potentially unsecure, check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46570264/6445270

Comment: Sorry removing from Accepted answer. As you know, temp files are potentially insecure. And we were looking for a better approach for security purposes only. Accepting  KaurJ's answer as to its more convincing. I had clearly asked in the question for an approach other than writing content into a temp file.

Answer (score 4):

I took a different approach and used the **init_poolmanager** to set the ssl context. I avoid patching, so it will only work with Session objects.

E.x.:

```
#pip install requests pyOpenSSL

import OpenSSL
import requests
import requests.hooks
from urllib3 import Retry
from urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl import PyOpenSSLContext
from urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context


class ClientSideCertificateHTTPAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    DEFAULT_PROTOCOL = create_urllib3_context().protocol

    def __init__(self, *args, cert, key, protocol=DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, **kwargs):
        self._cert = cert
        self._key = key
        self._protocol = protocol
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = PyOpenSSLContext(self._protocol)
        kwargs["ssl_context"] = ctx
        ctx._ctx.use_certificate(self._cert)
        ctx._ctx.use_privatekey(self._key)
        return super().init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)


def main():
    cert = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDnjC....cUkiz -----END CERTIFICATE-----")
    key = OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIDnjC....cUkiz -----END CERTIFICATE-----", b"passphrase_goes_here")

    adapter = ClientSideCertificateHTTPAdapter(cert=cert, key=key, max_retries=Retry(total=10, backoff_factor=0.5))
    session = requests.Session()
    session.mount("https://www.hotmail.com/", adapter)
    session.get("https://www.hotmail.com/api/v2/mail")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Nice solution, but starting with `urllib3` release `1.26.12` this will give a deprecation warning `'urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl' module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release of urllib3 2.x. Read more in this issue: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2680`. Use `1.26.11` to avoid the warning message.

Comment: @johlo It should be easy to just use OpenSSL directly, as PyOpenSSLContext comment in file is: " I am a wrapper class for the PyOpenSSL ``Context`` object. I am responsible
    for translating the interface of the standard library ``SSLContext`` object
    to calls into PyOpenSSL." and `__init__` is basically `self._ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(self.protocol)`

Answer (score 0):

Since i cannot have additional dependencies as openssl, here is alternative using `requests` library and temporary file:

```
import contextlib
import os
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

import requests

cert_key_str = """
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
"""

cert_str = """
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
"""

url = "https://..."


@contextlib.contextmanager
def create_temporary_file(suffix=None):
    """
    Context that introduces a temporary file.
    Adapted from:
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/57701186/5818549

    Creates a temporary file, yields its name, and upon context exit, deletes it.
    (In contrast, tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() provides a 'file' object and
    deletes the file as soon as that file object is closed, so the temporary file
    cannot be safely re-opened by another library or process.)

    Args:
      suffix: desired filename extension (e.g. '.mp4').

    Yields:
      The name of the temporary file.
    """
    try:
        temporaty_file = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=suffix, delete=False)
        temporaty_filename = temporaty_file.name
        temporaty_file.close()
        yield temporaty_filename
    finally:
        os.unlink(temporaty_filename)


with (
    create_temporary_file() as cert_filename,
    create_temporary_file() as key_filename
):
    with (
        open(cert_filename, "w") as cert_file,
        open(key_filename, "w") as key_file
    ):
        cert_file.write(cert_str)
        key_file.write(cert_key_str)

    final_conn = requests.get(
        url,
        cert=(cert_filename, key_filename),
    )
    print(final_conn.text)
```